# CSS table and parent div not following their height and width attributes? Jquery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dygraphs

I have a table(graphtable) inside a div(graphdiv) inside a div(half).

when i shrink half using jquery resizable the graphtable and graphdiv both increase in size. however using google developer tools the actual css of these elements have changed to the correct size.

inside the lowest div table is a dygraph which should resize to it's parent when the resize function is called on it's class.

i'm at a loss at how the css could say one thing and i could see another?

```
for(var i = 0; i<graphArray.length-1; i++){
    $( "#"+i ).resize(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();
        $(this).find(".graph").height(height);
        $(this).find(".graph").width(width*0.68);
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").height(height);
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").width(width*0.68);
        window.graphArray[$(this).attr('id')].resize();
    });
}
```

```css
.half{
background-color:#F2F2F2; 
width:48%;
height:50%;
border: 1px solid;
margin-top:1%;
float:left;
}
.graph{
width: 68%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
display:table;
}
.graphtable{
background-color:#F5F5F5; 
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<?php
echo "<div class='half' id='$i' name='".$graph['graph_id']."' style='position:absolute; top:".$top."px; left:".$left."px'>";
echo "<div id='graph' class='graph'>";
echo "<table id='graphtable$i' class='graphtable' style='width:100%; height:100%'></table>";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="dragger">Drag</div>';
echo '<div class="resizer">+</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

I have tride using .atrr on both the graph div and graphTable as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is an additional div that dygraph is bound to, so i added the two lines below to fix the resize problem. i'm sure there is a nicer way to do what i have done here, but at the moment it works. i will deal with performance at a later date

```
for(var i = 0; i<graphArray.length-1; i++){
    $( "#"+i ).resize(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();
        $(this).find(".graph").height(height);
        $(this).find(".graph").width(width*0.68);
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").height(height);
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").width(width*0.68);
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").find("div").width(width*0.68); //added
        $(this).find(".graph").find(".graphtable").find("div").height(height); //added
        window.graphArray[$(this).attr('id')].resize();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs only redraws when the window resizes. (Unfortunately, there's no event it can listen to for more general `<div>` resizes).

You can work around this by calling [`resize()`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#resize) on the dygraph to tell it to re-inspect its containing div.

Comment: yes unfortunately i do already do this, but it's resizing to the wrong sized container :/

Comment: @danvk Could you show an example of this workaround? Thx